# Asp.net troubles with file uploads

Tags: c#, asp.net

Our company has a form setup on our website for scholarship applications and I am having an issue with getting file uploads to work. I am using an asp.net page in C# to handle the form data.

From the form:

```
<form id="scholarForm" name="scholarForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" runat="server" action="upload_form.aspx">

<input id="transcript" type="file" />
```

The asp.net page handling the data (code edited for relevance):

```
protected HttpPostedFile transcript;

transcript = Request.Files["transcript"];

transcript.SaveAs(@"c:\Dollars Applicants\" + fullName + "_" + memberNumber + @"\" + transcript.FileName);
```

This just produces a null reference error and I am not sure why.  I have tried uploading several different file types with no success.

Comment: Try add name tag to input like `<input id="transcript" name="transcript" type="file" />` and check the Request.Files collection in Watch window on debug mode if it contains any file. Also keep in mind that IIS has default limitation on the file size, you can change it in web.config

Comment: @lavrik that worked but now I am receiving a "The given path's format is not supported." error?

Comment: Nevermind, figured that out as well, needed to use the Path.GetFileName.

Comment: @Spacemancraig glad to help :) When posting any form the input/select name tag will actually the thing you see on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a `FileUpload` control. (Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx)

Form code:

```
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fuTranscript" />
```

Code behind:

```
if (fuTranscript.HasFile)
{
    fuTranscript.SaveAs(@"c:\Dollars Applicants\" + fullName + "_" + memberNumber + @"\" + fuTranscript.FileName);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work because the actual form page is just standard .asp and not an .aspx

Comment: Ah fair enough. There's usually a good reason, I'm glad you got it sorted anyway =]